# propagating Excel data

Tags: microsoft-excel, merge, combine

Propagate might not be the correct word, but the answers I found to "merge" and "combine" questions don't seem to apply.

I have two completely different sheets of data. For example: sheet1 might have a column of items, and sheet2 might have a column of colors. I need to end up with 2 columns on a sheet containing every possible combination of the columns from the other 2 sheets.

So in the example above, if sheet1 has 140 items and sheet2 has 17 colors, I need sheet3 to have an item column, a color column, and 2,380 records (one for each item and color combination possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example that you can adapt.

Save we have **7** items in column **A** and **3** colors in column **B**.  Running this short macro:

```
Sub combine()
    Dim K As Long, i As Long, j As Long, Nitems As Long, Ncolors As Long

    K = 1
    Nitems = 7
    Ncolors = 3

    For i = 1 To Nitems
        For j = 1 To Ncolors
            Cells(K, "C").Value = Cells(i, "A").Value & "," & Cells(j, "B").Value
            K = K + 1
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

will produce this in column **C**:

[image]

Comment: I'll give this a shot, but I'll still need to break out the result into two separate columns.

Comment: @MarkAlexander  That would be a simple modification.

Comment: Yup, it was simple enough. I just changed the Cells line to these 2 Cells lines:

Comment: Cells(K, "C").Value = Cells(i, "A").Value
Cells(K, "D").Value = Cells(j, "B").Value